# SQL User-Defined Functions in Linq to Entities

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to call a user defined sql function in my linq statement using entity framework. The function is called `GetXml`, and takes 2 strings called "data" and "path" and returns a string. My Data Model is called `XmlDataModel`. I included the function definition in the edmx file as so:

```
    <Function Name="GetXml" ReturnType="varchar(max)"   Schema="dbo">
      <Parameter Name="path" Type="varchar(max)" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="data" Type="varchar(max)" Mode="In" />
    </Function>
```

I have the following declaration of the method in my code:

```
    [EdmFunction("XmlDataModel.Store", "GetXml")]
    public string GetXml(string path, string data)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method can only be used in a LINQ-toEntities query");
    }
```

And the following linq statement:

```
var test = from e in this.ObjectContext.Events 
           where GetXml("a", "b") == "test" select e.EventSpecificData;
```

My problem is that when I attempt to view the result set, I get the following message:

> The specified method 'System.String GetXml(System.String,
>   System.String)' on the type 'RIAServicesLibrary1.Web.XmlDomainService'
>   cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because
>   the instance over which it is invoked is not the ObjectContext over
>   which the query in which it is used is evaluated.

It seems to be recognizing that I have the method defined, because when I take out the `[EdmFunction]` tag I get a different message. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried making the method static?